# How to load javascript with third party dependency using nashorn

Tags: java, nashorn

Currently I am using jvm-npm to load javascript into my java code via Nashorn, but my javascript code in turn uses lodash. So when I try to run the code, and at the point where I require lodash, I encounter the following error,

```
javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot read property "prototype" from undefined in <directory>/resources/jvm-npm.js at line number 108 at column number 8

Cannot load module lodash LOAD_ERROR at jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:467)
```

Comment: do you get any solution for it?